# How is default routing interface determined

Tags: linux, networking, routing, networkmanager

TLDR: default routing interface is somehow determined by internet availability on one of the physical interfaces, the question is how exactly.

Setup: embedded Linux ARM board with two network interfaces: radio modem (managed by standalone script that starts pppd) and Ethernet (managed by NetworkManager, "method=auto"), Ethernet comes up first.

If Ethernet cable is plugged into a router, eth0 becomes default interface (as shown by 'route' command).

If instead, it is plugged into a PC, where DHCP server is running on Ethernet interface, but there's no routing/it's isolated (so internet is not reachable through it), radio becomes default route.

So in both cases, eth0 gets IP address via DHCP, but only if Internet is actually available through it, it becomes default route.

How does it work exactly? Is it done by NetworkManager may be?

Comment: There is more then 1 way this could happen, but more likely then not each device gets a default gateway via DHCP,  but the metric for the WIFI default gateway is lower then the Ethernet card (which is a logical default as Ethernet will usually be faster and more reliable) so Ethernet device is preferred if available.  You should be able to verify this by looking at the route table.

Comment: Check output of `ip route` in both configurations. If it is different, it happens via something that is executed on ethernet plug/unplug. First place I'd look for such a hotplug event is in udev, then trace what it calls.

Comment: @davidgo: thank you, this was the case, so if you post it as an answer I'll accept.

What happened is that in the second case (Ethernet plugged into a PC), DHCP server was configured w/o specifying "routers" option, and so ARM board simply didn't get any routing information about that interface, and used radio instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

davidgo's guess was correct: in case of manually configured DHCP server, device didn't receive gateway IP address (only its own), and so corresponding interface wasn't used for routing.

To hopefully make this answer more helpful and generic, other things equal interface with lowest metrics is selected, and Ethernet has lower metric than radio for example. In this particular case things weren't equal however.